# inequality for an integrable real valued function with a compactly supported fourier transform 

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be an integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$ where  support($\hat{f}$) $\subseteq$ [$-\gamma, \gamma$] for some $ 0 < \gamma < 1$

Prove that | $f(x) - f(0)$| $ \leq c \gamma$ |x| $\underset{ y \in \mathbb{R}}{sup}(1+|y|)|f(y)|$ for some absolute constant $c$.

Comment: Maybe math.SE is a better place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can successively establish the following:

$$\| f \|_2\le C\sup (1+|y|)|f(y)|,$$

$$\|\hat f\|_2\le C\|f\|_2,$$

$$\|f'\|_\infty\le C\gamma^{3/2}\|\hat f\|_2.$$

Here $\|\cdot\|_p$ denotes the $L^p$-norm. The last inequality uses the assumption about the support of $\hat f$.

Comment: how did you get the first inequality?


Comment: $$\int f^2\,dy=\int f^2(1+|y|)^2(1+|y|)^{-2}\,dy$$
$$\le [\sup |f(y)|(1+|y|)]^2\int (1+|y|)^{-2}\,dy.$$